# how to set numbers of copies to print in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I need to print 2 invoice copies; one for the customer and one for the counter. I'm using Crystal Report 8 with Vb.Net 2005. Can anyone give me a direction for this?

I have tried this, but nothing happens. DT is my datatable

```
Dim x As New crptInvoice
x.SetDataSource(DT)
x.PrintToPrinter(2, True, 1, 2)
crptViewer.ReportSource = x
crptViewer.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PrinttoPrinter to specify N Copies of report to print

```
rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(2, True, 1, 1)
```

which reads as:

`2   = nCopies as integer
True = collated as Boolean
1    = StartpageN as integer
1    = EndpageN as Integer`

also, your line

```
crptViewer.ReportSource = x    
crptViewer.Refresh()
```

is used if you want your report to be viewed using a reportViewer hence the name `crptViewer`

while `PrinttoPrinter` automatically sends your report to the print queue